# SharePoint Internal Field Name

Tags: jquery, infopath, spservices

I am using SPServices to update a field, however it is not updating and causing no ends of frustration.

I have been able to update other fields using this code so I can only come to the conclusion that the internal field name is incorrect.

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "UpdateListItems",
async: false,
batchCmd: "Update",
listName: "Staff Rewards",
ID: $(this).attr("ows_ID"),
valuepairs: [["Processed%5Fx0020%5FDate", "Processed"]],
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

}


});
```

The field name in InfoPath 2010 is "Processed Date", however once promoted the field name has become "Processed_x0020_Date" in SharePoint using the view URL and in the Column Settings URL the field name is: Processed%5Fx0020%5FDate

I have tried all of these field names and still can't get the list to update!

Answer (score 2):

Using the syntax with `valuepairs`, an array of column [StaticNames](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Glossary&referringTitle=UpdateListItems&ANCHOR#StaticName) and values have to be specified:

```
$().SPServices({
operation: "UpdateListItems",
async: false,
batchCmd: "Update",
listName: "Staff Rewards",
ID: $(this).attr("ows_ID"),
valuepairs: [["Processed_x0020_Date", "Processed"]],
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

   }
});
```

In addition, make sure that the proper List Item Id is passed for an Update operation:

```
$(this).attr("ows_ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally figured it out !!, had to use "Inspect Element" to check what SharePoint thinks as the Internal Name of my field and would you believe it... it seems for some reason, for longer names SharePoint just terminates them after what looks like 32 characters....my field name (Internal Name) shown in one of the comments in the final HTML (saw using "Inspect Element") was "Previous_x0020_Request_x0020_Sta"  where the Display name I have is "Previous Request Status"

this is weird, how would someone know this :-(  Oh SharePoint!!

I might be wrong in my conclusion of internal names being terminated after 32 characters, but my code now WORKS!! using that truncated name....so may be its something in SpServices if not SharePoint.... but to the best of my knowledge ....this seems like a SharePoint problem...thats what it looks like for now.

Comment: i understand this is an old post, just to be clear I was facing same issue, stumbled on this post, posted a message asking if anyone ever found an answer to this but that was removed apparently because it was a question not an answer. Fortunately I found a solution later so thought I 'd post it here so anyo0ne else who faces same issue in future and stumbles on this post also gets an answer.

Comment: You shouldn't use inspect element for this. Instead, go to your list settings and click on one of the fields. Then, in the URL you will see the Internal Name.